# How to execute Javascript in Chrome in the context of the current website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This is an XY question. I am trying to execute javascript using chrome-cli on mac in a particular tab. Simple javascript like alert(0) executes as expected. However, if referencing object properties of the website in question I get the error 'name not defined'. The same javascript that doesn't work from chrome-cli works perfectly from the javascript console.

i.e. I can access window.potato from the console but chrome-cli gives me potato is not defined at anonymous.

Listing the sub-properties of window from both the chrome console and chrome-cli with the following javascript shows that some properties are missing.

`for(var b in document.defaultView){
    if (window.hasOwnProperty(b))console.log(b);}`

What can I do?

Comment: Would something like tampermonkey do what you want? If not would something like nightmare.js do what you want?

Comment: Pretty much everything is detected on this site, tampermonkey, selenium, etc. However, chrome-cli appears to work. Im just not sure why I cannot access the properties I need.